# Youtube video upload limit exceeded

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I use this cmd application https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload

After uploading 50 videos i am getting this error:

```
[RequestError] Server response: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.video",
    "reason": "uploadLimitExceeded",
    "message": "The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload."
 }
}
```

And after this error i can upload 1 video per 15 minutes. But after waiting for aproximatley 2 hours i can upload 50 more videos but it does not work everytime. Sometimes even after waiting for 3 hours i still can't upload 50 videos.

Also i never exceeded my quota limit. 
My quota statistic:

[Queries per day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq2n6.png)

Till 20th of march i was getting this error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.common",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized."
 }
}
```

Рow did you solve it? How do you upload videos to youtube in large quantities?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube video uploads rejected before API quota limit reached](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998086/youtube-video-uploads-rejected-before-api-quota-limit-reached)

Comment: As of today I received this error after uploading 100 videos.

Answer (score 5):

> [badRequest (400)  uploadLimitExceeded](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#videos_youtube.videos.insert) The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload.

This is a user based quota which can not be upgraded.  It means that the user in question has exceed their upload limit for the day.  The YouTube API has a slightly different quota system than other Google APIs. The ones listed in developer console are just the general ones.  You should check [calculating quota usage](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#calculating-quota-usage)

> - 200,000 read operations that each retrieve two resource parts.
> - 10,000 write operations and 90,000 additional read operations that each retrieve two resource parts.
> - **400 video uploads, 1500 write operations, and 50,000 read operations that each retrieve two resource parts**.

This quota should reset at midnight West Coast USA time.

> Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized.

Means that either your access token or your refresh token is no longer working.  You should either use the access token to get a new refresh token.  Or re authenticate the application and get a new refresh token.  Yes refresh tokens can expire under different circumstances.

Comment: So, as i can see, i can upload up to 400 videos, but right now i stuck in quota limit after only about 50 videos. And that's the main question.

Comment: This is the third question I have seen about this in the last few weeks.  I think Google has changed something everyone is being locked to 50 videos now then only one every 15 minutes until they reach the 400.  I haven't been able to find any info on it nor have I gotten a response from my queries to Google.

Comment: Do you know if there is another limit after a few days of constant uploads? I have been upload videos for the last 4-5 days (approx 100 per day) but since yesterday morning I keep receiving `Error 400`.

Comment: The only thing i have gotten back from the YouTube team is that nothing has changed.    But its weird that its not documented.

Comment: Any idea how can I contact the team? The data I am uploading is scientific data. We are trying to update a database we created a few years ago (http://wormbehavior.mrc-lmb.cam.ac.uk/strain.php?strain=222&pagenum=2). We are fine to delete the old videos if necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't.  You are just going to have to slow down your uploads I think.

Answer (score 5):

I have also received the same message. This is due to changes for limiting those who try to spam-post videos.

In comment person from Google explains:

> Thanks for this report. I can confirm this behavior is intended;
>   currently you are limited to uploading **100 videos per day**. Throttling
>   may occur after a burst of upload activity.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35919708#comment10

As regards to throttling:

[comment 16](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35919708#comment16)

> Fwiw: The limit is 100 videos per day, but you can **only upload 50
>   videos at once**. After that, you have to wait ~15 minutes to upload
>   another video.

[comment 17](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35919708#comment17) (Person from Google):

> I can confirm #16 is correct. The limit is 100, with rate control
>   after 50.

Update:

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43182386/5251960) on April 3rd, 2017 (later than original comments in forum on Mar 21, 2017) from Google representative

> We **don't have any 50 videos per day limit anymore** tell the truth, but
>   we have antispam algorithms which may temporary suspend your Upload
>   function.