# YouTube API Quota limit do not exceeded but exceeded, why?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

It's my quota usage from console.developers.google.com:

```
YouTube Data API v3
Queries per day
    165 553 / 1 000 000
YouTube Data API v3
Queries per 100 seconds
    — / 3 000 000
YouTube Data API v3
Queries per 100 seconds per user
    — / 300 000
```

But I got:

```
[ { domain: 'youtube.video',
    reason: 'uploadLimitExceeded',
    message: 'The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload.' } ],
```

Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube video upload limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43078858/youtube-video-upload-limit-exceeded)

Answer (score 1):

You can only upload a set amount of videos to YouTube a day, this is not a quota of the API.

Comment: and the amount is 50?

Comment: last year I uploaded more than 1000 a day, but using client api.