# Setting thumbnail via API causes 503 backendError

Tags: php, youtube-api, thumbnails, youtube-data-api

We have a mobile based video editor which uploads peoples videos and thumbnails to an AWS S3 bucket. This then launches an AWS SWF process to encode, upload video, upload thumbnail and wait for processing of said video before telling the user their video is finished. Each user uses their own access tokens so videos are uploaded to their own YouTube channels.

This has been fine for the past 12 months or so, throwing the occasional backendError on thumbnail upload from the YouTube end, which we have a retry strategy which will wait 1, 3, 8, 15 etc, seconds. By the second or third retry the YouTube servers have sorted themselves out and everything is great again.

As of 2017-09-17 17:29 (AEST) none of our videos have managed to upload their thumbnail. System throws a Google_Service_Exception with status code of 503 and response body of,

> {  "error": {   "errors": [    {
>       "domain": "global",
>       "reason": "backendError",
>       "message": "Backend Error"    }   ],   "code": 503,   "message": "Backend Error"  } }

At this time, no server packages were updated, neither was any of our own code or used composer packages.

I tried revoking my access token, generated my own a new project and new API key/secret on a different account and still got the same error processing thumbnail on our test server (should rule out rate limiting, which we are very far below any restrictions).

Video upload still works fine. Editing video title from our system still works fine (means access token is functional and has required scopes t set a thumbnail if the channel allows it). Manually uploading a thumbnail directly to YouTube still works fine (rules out the channel itself having an issue).

I even re-downloaded the [sample code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set) and created a new test and it still fails. The specific line it fails at in all cases is

```
$status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
```

I have no idea what could be causing this sudden issue if nothing changed on our end, all images are 1920x1080 jpgs well under 2mb, completely different project and access tokens, completely new sample code. And I assume if everyone using the YouTube data API got this error over the past 24 hours there would be a lot more posts about it. So not sure what else to try from our end.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: 
Well... this is odd. I managed to upload via command line from our server with cURL.

```
curl -X POST -F "image=@thumbnail_test.jpg" "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/thumbnails/set?videoId=dCdQ2tJ5wIs&key={REMOVED}&access_token={REMOVED}"
```

And that worked fine. So that rules out issue with our server (IP blocked or something), issue with our access tokens or issue with our client_id key. It also somehow rules out YouTube backend behaving badly (assuming cURL and php connect via the same mechanisms).

That only leaves me with, our uploading of thumbnails to YouTube (and only thumbnails) now fail from PHP with no server or server code changes, but using identical access tokens and keys via cURL in the command line work fine.

EDIT 2:
I have upload a sample [here on github](https://github.com/ytn3rd/youtube-php-thumbnail-test) (includes a sample image and composer.json files). It has 2 samples in 1. Shows the script failing with youtube php sdk, but then working successfully with a curl request using the same credentials. Script does not include getting an access or refresh token.

The main test.php script is as follows.

```
<?php 

define('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID', 'REPLACE_ME');
define('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET', 'REPLACE_ME');

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$token = [
    'access_token' => 'REPLACE_ME',
    'refresh_token' => 'REPLACE_ME',
    'token_type' => 'Bearer',
    'expires_in' => '3600',
    'created' => REPLACE_ME
];

$youtube_id = 'REPLACE_ME';
$thumbnail_path = realpath('thumbnail.jpg');


/*
// Doing the exact same request in cURL works fine.
$data = [
    'filedata' => new CURLFile($thumbnail_path, 'image/jpeg', basename($thumbnail_path)),
];      
// Execute remote upload
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$token['access_token'],
]);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/thumbnails/set?videoId='.$youtube_id.'&key='.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
*/



// Based on php sample from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set
$client = new Google_Client();   
$client->setClientId(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes([
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly', 
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube', 
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
]);

$client->setAccessType('offline');  

// If you want to use a refresh token instead to get an access token from it.
//$token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($refresh_token);
//var_dump($token);
$client->setAccessToken($token);

$service = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

try
{
    // Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
    // reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
    // value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
    // Parameters to MediaFileUpload are:
    // client, request, mimeType, data, resumable, chunksize.
    $client->setDefer(true);
    $request = $service->thumbnails->set($youtube_id);
    $client->setDefer(false);
    $mimeType = 'image/jpeg';

    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
        $client,
        $request,
        $mimeType,
        null,
        true,
        $chunkSizeBytes
    );

    $filesize = filesize($thumbnail_path);
    echo "Filesize: $filesize\n";
    $media->setFileSize($filesize);

    // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
    $status = false;
    $handle = fopen($thumbnail_path, "rb");
    while (!$status && !feof($handle))
    {
        $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
        $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk); // The line where the Google_Service_Exception exception is thrown. 
    }

    fclose($handle);

    echo "Thumbnail uploaded success\n";                              
}
catch (Google_Service_Exception $err)
{
    echo $err->getMessage();
}
catch (Exception $err)
{
    echo $err->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Can you link to the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example for me so I can update the question with best practice for other readers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  You should not include your client id and secret i have my own.

Answer (score 0):

```
{  
   "error":{  
      "errors":[  
         {  
            "domain":"global",
            "reason":"backendError",
            "message":"Backend Error"
         }
      ],
      "code":503,
      "message":"Backend Error"
   }
}
```

Is a server error on Googles side.  There is nothing you can really do besides wait a few minutes and try again.   It is normally caused by going to fast.

Suggested action: Use [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#exponential-backoff), include a check before retrying non-idempotent requests.

Implementing exponential backoff

Exponential backoff is a standard error handling strategy for network applications in which the client periodically retries a failed request over an increasing amount of time. If a high volume of requests or heavy network traffic causes the server to return errors, exponential backoff may be a good strategy for handling those errors. Conversely, it is not a relevant strategy for dealing with errors unrelated to rate-limiting, network volume or response times, such as invalid authorization credentials or file not found errors.

Used properly, exponential backoff increases the efficiency of bandwidth usage, reduces the number of requests required to get a successful response, and maximizes the throughput of requests in concurrent environments.

Create requests are not idempotent. A simple retry is insufficient and may result in duplicate entities. Check whether the entity exists before retrying.

The flow for implementing simple exponential backoff is as follows.

1. Make a request to the API
2. Receive an error response that has a retry-able error code
3. Wait 1s + random_number_milliseconds seconds
4. Retry request
5. Receive an error response that has a retry-able error code
6. Wait 2s + random_number_milliseconds seconds
7. Retry request
8. Receive an error response that has a retry-able error code
9. Wait 4s + random_number_milliseconds seconds
10. Retry request
11. Receive an error response that has a retry-able error code
12. Wait 8s + random_number_milliseconds seconds
13. Retry request
14. Receive an error response that has a retry-able error code
15. Wait 16s + random_number_milliseconds seconds
16. Retry request
17. If you still get an error, stop and log the error.

Comment: I feel you didn't really read my question. We have exponential backoff implemented. System has been failing for 24 hours. CLI curl request with same access token, same key, same youtube video, same thumbnail, is working 100% of the time, but using the php sdk is failing 100% of the time. Both from the same machine.

Comment: I have read your question and there is no other solution for this problem.   It is a back end error or a flood protection issue.   If you have properly implemented exponential backoff then there is nothing else you can do.   If it is working with curl but not with PHP then have you considered you have a loop in your code someplace that is spamming the API causing PHP to always return a flood protection error?  As you have not include enough of your code to recreate the problem there inst much we can do.

Comment: Exponential backoff didn't let thumbnails upload, we have logged the error and that is why we came to SO after over 24 hours of failing ;) CLI works fine, via php fails. Environment hasn't been changed for about a week.

Comment: How much have you been uploading?  There is a limit.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/43087391/1841839   Have you tried waiting until tomorrow when your quota resets.

Comment: We are well under quota, CLI works repeatedly, php fails. Both from same machine with EXACT credentials and thumbnails for EXACT same video. If we were hitting an upload limit it would return 400 like that answer says. It would also mean CLI would be failing as well.

Comment: Please edit your question and add an example of what is failing so that it can be tested.   Without testing it this is the only answer i can give you.

Comment: Code used is pretty much identical to server code given in YouTube sample docs linked above. I will edit answer with the exact copy of that in a fully working git repo and maybe re-phrase why would curl CLI (soon to be curl in php) give a different result than php sdk which was last updated in july, on a system which has not been touched/updated in any way in the past 7 days.

Comment: the question has been updated with sample code which (at least with my client, secret, access token) that the YouTube data API with the php sdk fails, but doing a POST request with curl with the same credentials works fine.

Comment: And just out of no where, 4 days later it suddenly fixes itself. Was an issue within YT, but not one that would be replicable across all their SDKs for some reason (as in, again, server was not touched, remote code suddenly works, test code used above suddenly works). Exponential backoff wasn't the solution.

Answer (score 0):

And just out of no where, 4 days later it suddenly fixes itself. Was an issue within YT, but not one that would be replicable across all their SDKs for some reason (as in, again, server was not touched, remote code suddenly works, test code used locally suddenly works).