# Limit of video sends via youtube api per day

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, quota

What is daily limit of send videos to youtube via google api youtubev3?

I found that this is 50 videos per day or 1000000quotas per day.

Is that possible that I got banned for uploading small tests videos today? I was sending the same video multiple times and then removing it from my youtube channel.
And what about this limits, how to check if I used 50 videos today or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube video upload limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43078858/youtube-video-upload-limit-exceeded)

Comment: this one to [Youtube video uploads rejected before API quota limit reached](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42998086/1841839)

Answer (score 1):

The upload video quota is 50 videos per day.  It will reset at midnight West Cost USA time.  This quota can not be extended.

The best way to test if you have passed the quota is to just try the error returned will tell you that you have reached your limit for today.

[Calculating quota](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#calculating-quota-usage)

A video upload has a cost of approximately 1600 units.  Which should mean that you have 400 video uploads.   However about a year ago we noticed that they have changed it so that the max uploads per day is around 50.   I have tried several times to get some information from google about this change and have the documentation updated but they haven't done anything about it.

Comment: I got error 
"The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload."
Is it possible to buy more videos per day?

Comment: No this is not an extendable quota that i am aware of.

Comment: Do you know any differrent services that enable to upload video via api without limits?

Comment: The YouTube API is the only API able to upload to YouTube.  Even if someone else made another API using the YouTube API it would be bound by the same limitations you are seeing now.

Comment: I mean, do you know any different place like YouToube which allow to upload and watching videos?

Comment: No i dont sorry