# Video insert results in "uploadLimitExceeded" exception

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are using the youtube api to upload multiple videos to channels we have permissions to. When uploading a batch of videos via the api it results in "uploadLimitExceeded" exception. The message says "The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload". It is unclear what limit exactly is exceeded.
In the google cloud console the only user related quota we have is "Queries per minute per user" and its 180k. So if a video insert is 1600 it means the quota should be 112 videos per user per minute however when tried to upload 81 videos, only 10 succeeded and all the rest failed with the "uploadLimitExceeded" exception. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you share which APIs are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Youtube video upload limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43078858/youtube-video-upload-limit-exceeded)