# Upload more than 50 Videos using YouTube API

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a new channel with no videos uploaded yet. When I tried uploading some 500 videos I had using the YouTube Data API, the upload process stopped after about 50 videos. I do not understand how my quota limit reached 300,000 (the per 100 second default limit) as the quota required for uploading 1 video is just 1600. I have to upload around 500-600 videos every day as the nature of my business is such. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube video uploads rejected before API quota limit reached](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998086/youtube-video-uploads-rejected-before-api-quota-limit-reached)

Answer (score 1):

```
[RequestError] Server response: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.video",
    "reason": "uploadLimitExceeded",
    "message": "The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload."
 }
}
```

This is a user based quota and not a project based quota. It has nothing to do with what you are seeing on the Google Developer console.

The quota used to be:

> 400 video uploads, 1500 write operations, and 50,000 read operations that each retrieve two resource parts.

Google has apparently changed how the quota works.  A user can upload 50 videos then only one video every 15 minutes until the quota resets.   Quota resets at midnight west cost USA time.

I have an email out to the team looking for feed back on this.