# YouTube API uploadLimitExceeded even though quota is not exceeded

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

My quota usage is 250,692 (out of 1,000,000 in the developers console).
Even though I'm getting:
`Error making YouTube API call: googleapi: Error 400: The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload., uploadLimitExceeded`.

This happened after uploading 98 videos of an estimated grand total size of 0.5 TB. This is coincidentally (?) around 0.5 TB and 2 more than 96 (1 video every 15 minutes for a 24 hour day).

This is not the first time I'm hitting this barrier. It does not fully reset at any time, it's closer to slowly replenishing (previous reports say about 1 video every 15 minutes).

This is NOT:
- 50 videos limit as reported in previous stack overflow issues (there are number of those, none with an answer, none commented by YT API Developers to the best of my knowledge
- Google API quota issue
- any other publicly known quota

Ideally I'd like not to have this bottleneck. I'd be also happy with knowing the precise nature of the phenomena so I could plan around it.

Comment: That error message is telling you exactly whats wrong. You hit the upload limit per day. Probably rolling 24 hours. It has nothing to do with your API usage quota.

Comment: @MattiPrice this is a non documented limit. And it makes no sense, unless someone made a limit of 98 videos. Is this what you're telling me? `probably 24 hours`? I'm looking for an answer not some guesswork of a person who doesn't know anything. Sorry if I don't sound too nice - but the truth is that your contribution has 0 merit. I do appreciate however that you took some time to write a reply though. :)

Comment: Well good luck then. You clearly saw the other questions with the exact same issue and no official answer, this should be flagged as duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube video uploads rejected before API quota limit reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998086/youtube-video-uploads-rejected-before-api-quota-limit-reached)

Comment: @MattiPrice however this is different as they had 50 limit and it was long time ago, I do honores believe it's a different thing - even if the mechanics seem the same, the limit I'm reaching is clearly very different

Comment: Except it isn't. As it has been stated it doesn't appear to reset all at once, hence the likely rolling 24 hour limit unless they are doing something super weird. You just happen to be running into it on the second "day" so just shy of 100. Which.. is about 50 per day. The error message is exactly the same same as well. It's not magically some different error because you got it to run okay for the first 24 hours. Delay by a couple more minutes and it'll probably all work just fine. AND the other question is clearly tagged as using the API as well.