# use google api to upload videos got error 'The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload.'

Tags: youtube-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I use [googleapis nodejs client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) to upload my videos.for some reason, some videos have not been processed successfully, so I need upload them again,But I got some error:

> Error: The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload.

I googled some answers about these question ,like [Youtube video uploads rejected before API quota limit reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998086/youtube-video-uploads-rejected-before-api-quota-limit-reached)
,and I found Quotas page to see whether i reach the limit quotas.

[image]

As you can see, I did't reach the limit .But I also can not upload videos any more using api.

I want to know why .

By the way 
my googleapis version is v36.0.0.
my node version is v8.13.0

Comment: There could be a possibility that you are hitting the per user quota not the per project quota. And for the per user quota, the limit cannot be raised as what was mentioned in the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998086/youtube-video-uploads-rejected-before-api-quota-limit-reached) you have provided. You'll have to wait for the reset at 12 midnight.

Comment: It's a limit tied to the YouTube Account, not the API. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998086/youtube-video-uploads-rejected-before-api-quota-limit-reached

Comment: ok ,thanks all of you.