# The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When trying to upload videos via the YouTube Data API, I'm getting the infamous "The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload."

As per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53698917/use-google-api-to-upload-videos-got-error-the-user-has-exceeded-the-number-of-v#comment94263612_53698917), this limitation should've been gone after midnight, but I still get this error after waiting a day.

I'm not sure what data you need to identify our app, but I'm writing from Smartly.io, the project is called Dynamite production, and the id of the project is `dynamite-production`.

Let me know if you need more identification info AND how to retrieve those info, if needed.

Comment: Check you google console and see the quota of your API key, then, if you have quota and you still has this issue, search in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc) if someone else has the same or similar problem - or post a ticket there. I don't think this is a programming-related issue, but with the usage of the API.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure it has to do with quota limits, it's just not clear _which_ quota. My hunch it has to do with the _channel_, namely there is a per channel quota limit. Do you know if there is a document for that quota limitation?

Comment: Could you share please how many videos you have uploaded 24 hours before getting the error and in more general how much videos you have uploaded to the given channel ?