# Can't upload more than 100 videos with youtube api

Tags: upload, youtube-api

we implemented youtube api and requested quota extension with 3,000,000.
when uploading 100 videos, we can't upload any more.
Is there a limit or something?
how to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Youtube video uploads rejected before API quota limit reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998086/youtube-video-uploads-rejected-before-api-quota-limit-reached)

Comment: No,  we came across the same issue, but I can't find any solution in this page